# I'm having difficulties simulating physics equations in python using matplotlib & numpy

Tags: python, numpy, physics

I'm working on a physics simulation where particles collide together and I need to calculate the resulting velocities of the particles after the collision. For that, the following formulas are given (I have to use these, I've found other equations online which caused me different problems):

[image]

I've tried to recreate them like this:

```
def reflect_particle_velocity(Pa, Pb, Va, Vb, Ma, Mb):
    Vas = (np.sqrt(np.square(Va[0]) + np.square(Va[1])))
    Vbs = (np.sqrt(np.square(Vb[0]) + np.square(Vb[1])))
    Prel = [np.abs(Pa[0] - Pb[0]), np.abs(Pa[1] - Pb[1])]
    Vrel = [np.abs(Va[0] - Vb[0]), np.abs(Va[1] - Vb[1])]
    dotFactor = np.dot(Vrel, Prel) / np.dot(Prel , Prel)
    MaFact = (2 * Mb) / (Ma + Mb)
    MbFact = (2 * Ma) / (Ma + Mb)
    NewVa = [(Vas - (MaFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[0], (Vas - (MaFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[1]]
    NewVb = [(Vbs + (MbFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[0], (Vbs + (MbFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[1]]
return NewVa, NewVb
```

Where `Pa` is the 2D position of the first particle, `Pb` is the 2D position of the second particle, `Va` is the 2D velocity of the first particle, `Vb` is the 2D velocity of the second particle, Pa is the 2D position of the first particle, Pb is the 2D position of the second particle, `Ma` is the mass of the first particle and `Mb` is the mass of the second particle.

Using this code I get the following readings:

[image]

The green line being the total energy in the system. As you can see it's increasing massively, infact, the first few values are around 200 slowly going upward. What I've noticed is that somehow my code increases the velocity too much. either that or I've created a working perpetual motion machine...

What have I done wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the code used for generating data/displaying the energy over time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def step(pos, vel, mas, Na, Nb, R, dt, boxX, boxY):
    pos = step_particles_pos(pos, vel, dt)
    vel = step_particles_vel(vel, dt)
    vel = check_collisions_bbox(pos, vel, boxX, boxY, Na + Nb)
    vel = check_collisions_particles(pos, vel, mas, Na, Nb, R)
    return pos, vel


def step_particles_pos(pos, vel, dt):
    #return np.array([pos[:, 0] + (vel[:, 0] * dt), pos[:, 1] + (vel[:, 1] * dt) - 0.5 * (9.8 * np.square(dt))])
    pos[:, 0] = pos[:, 0] + (vel[:, 0] * dt)
    pos[:, 1] = pos[:, 1] + (vel[:, 1] * dt) - 0.5 * (9.8 * np.square(dt))
    return pos


def step_particles_vel(vel, dt):
    vel[:, 1] = vel[:, 1] - (9.8 * dt)
    return vel


def check_collisions_bbox(pos, vel, boxX, boxY, N):
    posMaskNy = np.zeros(np.shape(pos))
    posMaskPx = np.zeros(np.shape(pos))
    posMaskPy = np.zeros(np.shape(pos))

    posMaskNy = np.where(pos < 0, 1, posMaskNy)
    posMaskPx = np.where(pos > boxX, 1, posMaskPx)
    posMaskPy = np.where(pos > boxY, 1, posMaskPy)

    posMaskPx[:, 1] = 0
    posMaskPy[:, 0] = 0

    posMask =  posMaskNy + posMaskPx + posMaskPy

    posMask = np.where(posMask != 0, -1, posMask)
    posMask = np.where(posMask == 0, 1, posMask)

    vel = vel * posMask

    return vel


def reflect_particle_velocity(Pa, Pb, Va, Vb, Ma, Mb):
    Vas = (np.sqrt(np.square(Va[0]) + np.square(Va[1])))
    Vbs = (np.sqrt(np.square(Vb[0]) + np.square(Vb[1])))
    Prel = [np.abs(Pa[0] - Pb[0]), np.abs(Pa[1] - Pb[1])]
    Vrel = [np.abs(Va[0] - Vb[0]), np.abs(Va[1] - Vb[1])]
    dotFactor = np.dot(Vrel, Prel) / np.dot(Prel , Prel)
    MaFact = (2 * Mb) / (Ma + Mb)
    MbFact = (2 * Ma) / (Ma + Mb)
    NewVa = [(Vas - (MaFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[0], (Vas - (MaFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[1]]
    NewVb = [(Vbs + (MbFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[0], (Vbs + (MbFact * dotFactor)) * Prel[1]]
    return NewVa, NewVb


def check_collisions_particles(pos, vel, mas, Na, Nb, R):
    A = pos[:, 0]
    B = pos[:, 1]
    Xdiff = np.abs(A - A[:, np.newaxis])
    Ydiff = np.abs(B - B[:, np.newaxis])
    diff = np.triu(np.sqrt(np.square(Xdiff) + np.square(Ydiff)))
    diffMask = np.where(diff == 0 , R + 1, diff)
    diffMask = np.where(diffMask <= R , -1, diffMask)
    diffMask = np.where(diffMask > R , 0, diffMask)

    invertIDs = np.argwhere(diffMask)

    for int in invertIDs:
        vel[int[0]], vel[int[1]] = reflect_particle_velocity(pos[int[0]],
                                                             pos[int[1]],
                                                             vel[int[0]],
                                                             vel[int[1]],
                                                             mas[int[0]],
                                                             mas[int[1]])
    return vel


def get_kinetic_energy(vel, M, start, end):
    N = end - start
    results = np.zeros(N)
    factor = ( 1 / (2 * N) ) * M
    for i in range(0, N):
        results[i] = factor * np.dot(np.abs(vel[i]), np.abs(vel[i]))
    return results


def get_potential_energy(pos, M, start, end):
    N = end - start
    results = np.zeros(N)
    factor = ( 1 / N ) * M * 9.8
    for i in range(0, N):
        results[i] = factor * pos[i][1]
    return results


def get_average(a, n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, int(n)):
        sum = sum + a[i]
    return sum / n


Na = 30                 # number of A particles
Nb = 30                 # number of B particles
Ma = 0.025              # weight of A particles
Mb = 0.05               # weight of B particles
R = 0.04                # particle radius
T = 100                 # simulation time
dt = 0.004              # time increments
dts = 0.04              # measurement increments
stept = T / dt          # number of cycles in simulation
steps = T / dts         # number of measurements
ints = stept / steps    # interval between measurements
samples = 0             # number of measurements taken
qTimes = 10             # inverval of quiver display
qStep = T / qTimes      # number of steps between quiver displays

boxX = 8                # width of the bounding box
boxY = 16               # height of the bounding box

# generate random starting positions/velocities
# for the amount of particles in the simulation.
posX = np.random.rand(Na + Nb)
posY = np.random.rand(Na + Nb)
velX = np.random.rand(Na + Nb)
velY = np.random.rand(Na + Nb)

MA = np.full(Na, Ma)
MB = np.full(Nb, Mb)

mas = np.concatenate((MA, MB), axis=0)

timespace = np.linspace(0, T, int(steps))

# merge the two arrays into one containing tuples.
pos = np.array((posX * boxX, posY * boxY)).T
vel = np.array([velX, velY]).T

KEa = np.zeros(int(steps))
KEb = np.zeros(int(steps))
PEa = np.zeros(int(steps))
PEb = np.zeros(int(steps))
TE = np.zeros(int(steps))

# cycle stept amount of times
for i in range(0, int(stept)):
    # update all particles
    pos, vel = step(pos, vel, mas, Na, Nb, R, dt, boxX, boxY)
    if i % ints == 0:
        KEa[samples] = get_average(get_kinetic_energy(vel, Ma, 0, Na), Na)
        KEb[samples] = get_average(get_kinetic_energy(vel, Mb, Na, Na + Nb), Nb)
        PEa[samples] = get_average(get_potential_energy(pos, Ma, 0, Na), Na)
        PEb[samples] = get_average(get_potential_energy(pos, Mb, Na, Na + Nb), Nb)
        TE[samples] = KEa[samples] + KEb[samples] + PEa[samples] + PEb[samples]
        samples = samples + 1

#Energy over Time plot

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Time', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Energy', fontsize=16)
plt.plot(timespace, KEa, color="royalblue")
plt.plot(timespace, KEb, color="navy")
plt.plot(timespace, PEa, color="gold")
plt.plot(timespace, PEb, color="yellow")
plt.plot(timespace, TE, color="green")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you add the code used to generate the function arguments (Pa, Pb, etc.)? It's hard to tell what is going on if we cannot reproduce the example.

Comment: Is the denominator of the dotFactor correct?

Comment: @Angelos as far as I know yes... although it's kinda wierd

Comment: @BRHSM it looks like it is always 1. Maybe it needs to be '''np.dot(Prel , Prel)'''

Comment: @Angelos ahh that was something left from experimentation... the graph is from (Prel, Prel) though so I fixed the typo in the edit!

Comment: I get [this](https://ibb.co/j67HhmH) image when I run your code.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem I'm sorry, forgot to add a function checking they didn't go outside the bounding box... what you saw was kinetic energy increasing and potential energy decreasing...

Comment: This may be a numerical issue in `check_collisions_bbox`. When dealing with floats, testing for equality is unreliable. You could use `np.isclose` instead. For `example, mask = np.isclose(posMask, 0); posMask = np.where(mask, -1, posMask); posMask = np.where(~mask, 1, posMask)`. I get [this](https://ibb.co/QnCGQk2) output after the change.

Comment: it does look promising but is not entirely correct... from what I can see there is no velocity that way... (Blue lines are 0 because kinetic energy is 0)

Comment: @BRHSM I do not have the background to comment on the physical interpretation. However, the fact that changing `x == 0` to `np.isclose(x, 0)` leads to a drastic change in output suggests that the problem is in part numeric. The usual [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) may be  helpful.

Comment: @hilberts_drinking_problem well it's setting all velocities to 0 so I assume though your code above posMask is just a lot of 0's